# map for footstep_planner

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I use the ar_kinect package and ar_markers to recognize objects and calculate their position.

Now I like to create a map for the footstep_planner.

How can I create such a map with ROS? With packages can I use for this?

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50718/map-for-footstep_planner/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map for footstep_planner needs to be a regular obstacle map, as it is defined in [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid](http://ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html). For static maps, that can be a simple black & white bitmap that you send out with [map_server](http://ros.org/wiki/map_server).

If you get obstacle positions from artificial markers, you will have to create this obstacle map yourself.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1